# How to handle `MissingRequiredArgument` errors

Tags: python, error-handling, discord, discord.py

I was making a bot in the rewrite branch of discord.py and lets say this is my code:

```
@bot.command()
async def ok(ctx,con):
    try:
        await ctx.send(con)
    except commands.MissingRequiredArgument:
        await ctx.send('You did not give me anything to repeat!')
```

What I am trying to do is handle the MissingRequiredArgument error but the code i wrote still gives the error instead of returning `You did not give me anything to repeat!` I would appreciate it if someone would tell me how to handle it.
exact error:

```
Ignoring exception in command translate:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jatinder\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 892, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\jatinder\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 790, in invoke
    await self.prepare(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\jatinder\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 751, in prepare
    await self._parse_arguments(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\jatinder\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 679, in _parse_arguments
    kwargs[name] = await self.transform(ctx, param)
  File "C:\Users\jatinder\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 516, in transform
    raise MissingRequiredArgument(param)
discord.ext.commands.errors.MissingRequiredArgument: con is a required argument that is missing.
```

Comment: By the looks on the exception written on discord.py repo itself, it seems that MissingRequiredArgument is just an exception that happens when you're not passing the required argument, and ctx.send() method has one argument. Have you tried using await ctx.send(con) without any try/except statement and what it says if there is an error?

Comment: @lambda23 I did try it but it just gave the same error

Comment: What is the exact error (stack trace)? You may also want to include the discord.py version and check whether it's an (ongoing) issue on their GitHub repo.

Comment: @lambda23 added it and i will check their github

Comment: One note of your original code. You can probably just send the Discord message if con is a `None` instead of wrapping it in such way. It's better to avoid the method to throw an error instead of letting it to throw an error.

Also, I think `con` is the first arg instead of array of args of the command, you can use `*args` as second param of your method. That way, you'll use your arguments as an array and you can check whether your first argument (`args[0]`) is None, and then you'll send the message.

Answer (score 1):

This error cannot be handled by a try/except, I'm not sure why but I have two ways you can handle this.

#### First method:

---

```py
@bot.command()
async def ok(ctx, con=None):
    if con == None: return await ctx.send('You did not give me anything to repeat!')
    # Do whatever here, if you come here it means the user gave something to repeat
```

'con' is set to None by default (con=None). If a user doesn't give anything it'll stay None. But if a user gives something it'll be what (s)he gave.
The if-statement will detect if 'con' equals to None, if it does then it means the user returned nothing.

#### Second Method

---

```py
@bot.command()
async def ok(ctx, con):
    # Do whatever here, if you come here it means the user gave something to repeat

@bot.event
async def on_command_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.MissingRequiredArgument):
        print('You did not give me anything to repeat!')
```

I used `@bot.event` here meaning the error will be handled for all commands that don't have an argument (In other words commands that get the `MissingRequiredArgument` error)
If you want to work for only the 'ok' command, used `@ok.error` instead of `@bot.event`.

Comment: Also by the way if you use `@ok.error`, you can name `on_command_error` whatever you want

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this would be to use the error event.

```
@ok.error
async def on_command_error(error, ctx):
    await ctx.send(“You did not give me anything to repeat!”)
```

Please note the `@ok.error` is intentional as it allows it to only function for that command as to not interfere with ay other commands you have.

Comment: Commands don't have the attribute 'event'. So I think `@ok.event` won't work. Perhaps you meant `@ok.error`?

Comment: I did, my mistake!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that the other answer will work but this will

```
@bot.event
async def on_command_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, MissingRequiredArgument):
        await ctx.send("A parameter is missing")
```

Answer (score 0):

use an error catcher (checks for missing required argument error)

```py
@bot.command()
async def ok(ctx,con):
   await ctx.send(con)
@ok.error
async def okerror(ctx,error):
   if isinstance(error, commands.MissingRequiredArgument):
       await ctx.send("i need something to say")
   else:
      await ctx.send("The error that occured was"+str(error))
```